# How do I disable automatic text replacement in my NSTextViews?

Tags: macos

Our app has some non-rich-text NSTextViews that users can enter text into. When a user enters "..." into the text view, OS X automatically replaces it with an ellipsis character, which we don't want to happen. This needs to be something we disable for all users of our app, rather than relying on them to disable it themselves.

I expected this to be an NSUserDefaults setting, like the "ApplePressAndHoldEnabled" one, but I was unable to find anything in the docs about it. I found some information about the "WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled" preference that sounds like it does what we need, but setting it to "NO" doesn't seem to do anything for our app.

I've also looked at NSSpellChecker, which appears to provide the "isAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled" method to check whether text replacement happens, but no way to stop it happening for an application.

How can I disable this text replacement for our app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are settings in the nib file for this (select the NSTextView).  Unfortunately as of the latest version of OS X / Xcode, some of them seem to be broken so you may find that you have to send messages to your view from e.g. `-awakeFromNib` instead, e.g.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  [myTextView setAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled:NO];
  [myTextView setAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled:NO];
}
```

See the [documentation for `NSTextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the full set of methods.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there are equivalent methods on NSTextFieldCell that I could use to do the same thing for single-line edit controls?

Comment: Even single-line edit controls actually use an `NSTextView` for editing.  In the case of typical Cocoa controls, a shared text view called the *field editor* is used.  You can customise the field editor either by implementing `-windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:` on your `NSWindow`’s delegate, by overriding `-fieldEditor:forObject:` on your `NSWindow`, or by overriding `-setUpFieldEditorAttributes:` on your NSTextFieldCell.